# Android - Error Test GPS on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

i wanna test GPS on my android emulator but i find my apps has Error "Stopped Unexpectedly" when i try to run its on emulator.

here some sort of my codes 
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and main.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    if(location != null){
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
    }else{
        latLongString = "No location found";
    }
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is: \n" + latLongString);
}
```

import on my main.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

would you tell me why my apps getting error "stopped unexpectedly" when i try to run its on my emulator ?

thanks for helping me :)

Error from tracing : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
i have been using DDMS to set long and lat to this:
long: 112.8010100
lat : -7.2950700

Comment: Its better to provide stacktrace for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can mock the location in the emulator**

### Providing Mock Location Data

As you develop your application, you'll certainly need to test how well 
your model for obtaining user location works. This is most easily done 
using a real Android-powered 
device. If, however, you don't have a device, you can still test your 
location-based features by mocking location data in the Android emulator. 
There are three different ways to send your application mock location data: 
using Eclipse, DDMS, or the "geo" command in the emulator console.

Note: Providing mock location data is injected as GPS location data,
 so you must request location updates from GPS_PROVIDER in order for mock
 location data to work.

**Using Eclipse**

Select Window > Show View > Other > Emulator Control.

In the Emulator Control panel, enter GPS coordinates 
under Location Controls as individual lat/long coordinates,
 with a GPX file for route playback, or a KML file for 
multiple place marks. (Be sure that you have a device selected
 in the Devices panel—available from Window > Show View > Other > Devices.)

**Using DDMS**

With the DDMS tool, you can simulate location data a few different ways:

Manually send individual longitude/latitude coordinates to the device.
Use a GPX file describing a route for playback to the device.
Use a KML file describing individual place marks for sequenced 
playback to the device.
For more information on using DDMS to spoof location data, see Using DDMS.

**Using the "geo" command in the emulator console**

To send mock location data from the command line:

Launch your application in the Android emulator and open a terminal/console
 in your SDK's /tools directory.
Connect to the emulator console:
telnet localhost 
Send the location data:
geo fix to send a fixed geo-location.
This command accepts a longitude and latitude in decimal degrees, and
 an optional altitude in meters. For example:
geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 4392
geo nmea to send an NMEA 0183 sentence.
This command accepts a single NMEA sentence of type '$GPGGA' (fix data) or 
'$GPRMC' (transit data). For example:
geo nmea $GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62
For information about how to connect to the emulator console, see Using the 
Emulator Console.

Comment: +1 Excellent Answer! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: thanks for helping, but the problem is when i try to run my apps on emulator its give me Error "Stopped unexpectedly"