# Android - error when try to test GPS on Emulator

Tags: android

i wanna test a simple brief of using GPS on android. so i write a simple code like this :

```
public class main extends Activity{
LocationManager mLocationManager;
TextView tv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String locationprovider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationprovider);

    tv.setText("Last location lat:" + mLocation.getLatitude() + "long:" + mLocation.getLongitude());
}
```

}

also, on AndroidManifest i added uses-permission like this :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

but when i try to run at android emulator i get Error "Stopped Unexpectedly" and this apps closed. i added some try with DDMS too. but i dont have any idea about this error.

Comment: what says the logcat? which line does the crash occur in?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265005/android-error-test-gps-on-emulator/8265067#comment10173534_8265067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also had similar problems in real devices. The frequency at which the listener was receiving new locations was too high to update my TextViev. I solved it with a bit of synchronization, and skipping View refresh if it was being refreshed at that moment.

In your case, as you are not using a listener, I'd check for `NullPointerExceptions`.

Comment: problem solving. thans to @Mister smith i added sort code like this

if (location !=nul){
}else{}
thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using Google API for the Android Emulator that's why you are cant access the Google Map APı and get a crash like that.

Check this for more info about setting emulator for usage with Maps.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Comment: Google Map API is not needed to get GPS fixes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using it from the emulator and it doesn't have any gps related hardware.

here is a solution

To send mock location data from the command line:

Launch your application in the Android emulator and open a terminal/console in your SDK's /tools directory.
Connect to the emulator console:

```
telnet localhost <console-port>
```

Send the location data:
geo fix to send a fixed geo-location.
This command accepts a longitude and latitude in decimal degrees, and an optional altitude in meters. For example:

```
geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 4392
```

geo nmea to send an NMEA 0183 sentence.
This command accepts a single NMEA sentence of type '$GPGGA' (fix data) or '$GPRMC' (transit data). For example:

```
geo nmea $GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62
```

source : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

also see this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#console

Comment: i know about the emulator and device. but surely it is not about what you are considering. anyway thanks for your answer @Arun

Answer (score 0):

It is an `API KEY` issues. You can try to request a new `API KEY` on google map API key.
Your code is correct and didn't show any errors.

Perhaps this answer can help you solve your problems.